# get fields of an object with twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a problem on a personal project and need your help.

I have an entity `bien`, users can list all `bien` entities from the database in a table with all the fields of the entity. I'd like to make an administration page where people with proper access can choose the fields to display on this listing.

I created a system with a JSON file (`"field" => <boolean>`). I can get the admin choice and create the appropriate JSON, however there is a problem when I try to display the list with only the fields that are set to `true`. I wanted to display it with something like this: (you can see the former way to display the table which is now commented)

```
{% for bien in biens %}
    <tr>
    {% for categorie, affichage in donnee %}
        {% if affichage %}
            <td>{{ bien.{{ categorie }}}}</td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {# former way #}
    <td><a href="{{ path('bien_show', { 'id': bien.id }) }}">{{ bien.id }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ bien.titre }}</td>
    <td>{{ bien.description }}</td>
    <td>{{ bien.type }}</td>
    <td>{{ bien.surfaceHabitable }}</td>
    <td>{{ bien.nombrePiece }}</td>
    <td>{{ bien.nombreEtage }}</td>
    <td>{% if bien.sousSol %}Yes{% else %}No{% endif %}</td>
    <td>{{ bien.prix }}</td>
    <td>{{ bien.honoraire }}</td>
    <td>{{ bien.charge }}</td>
    <td>{{ bien.adresse }}</td>
    <td>{{ bien.codePostal }}</td>
    <td>{{ bien.ville }}</td>#}
    <td>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('bien_show', { 'id': bien.id }) }}">Voir</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('bien_edit', { 'id': bien.id }) }}">Editer</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </td>
    {# end former way #}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But I have an error on the line

`<td>{{ bien.{{ categorie }}}}</td>`

> Expected name or number.

I think I am not making it the right way (I also tried `{{ bien.categorie }}`without goodthe proper result).

Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html This should help you.

Comment: Salut, this syntax does not exist in twig `{{ bien.{{ categorie }}}}`, I'm trying to undestand what you're doing in the second loop, do you know that inside the second loop `categorie` is the key and the value is `affichage` of the array `donnee` ?  which means you are trying to access `{{ bien.keyOfAnArray }}` which I think is not an attribute in your object

Comment: thank you very much, i looked in twig documentation but didn't find this. Problem solved